# How to selectively show modals in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm building an app that is very similar to the Calendar app on iOS. I have a tab-based app that should sometimes trigger modals and other times cards, based on the screen being shown. In Apple's Calendar app, if you click on an event, you'll get a normal (slide from side or "card") transition, but if you click on the "+" button, you'll get a modal (bottom up) transition. I'd like to achieve something similar. The problem now is I can only get either all modals or all card transitions.

```
const CalendarTab = createStackNavigator(
    {
        CalendarView: {screen: CalendarView},
        ViewEvent: {screen: ViewEvent}, // This should be a "card" transition
        AddEvent: {screen: AddEvent}, // This should be a "modal" transition
    },
    {
        mode: "modal", // This shouldn't be hard-coded
        initialRouteName: "CalendarView",
    }
);

const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Calendar: CalendarTab,
    Settings: SettingsTab,
},
{
    initialRouteName: "Calendar",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarVisible: navigation.state.index === 0, // This should only apply to modals
    });
}

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <TabStack />;
    }
}
```

Edit: I did find a partial solution here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/707#issuecomment-299859578, but it causes the headers to get messed up and is generally a brittle solution.

Comment: Maybe, this is not `react-native-navigation` but `react-navigation`. Because react-navigation is a _static_ router, wrapping `CalendarView` with StackNavigator and add `AddEvent` to it as different routeName (e.g. `PushAddView`) is orthodox method I think.

Comment: @mmtootmm Yes, you're right! I fixed the tag.

Comment: I have a similar situation and found a little solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524809/react-navigation-dynamically-setting-mode-setting-header-renders-double-an It still does not have text on the back button though... Did you solve this issue? If yes could you post an answer explaining what you did?

Comment: @J.Hesters I hadn't found a fix, but when I tried your solution, it seemed to work. What's strange is that I thought I tried this approach before and it didn't work previously. I did upgrade React Navigation from v2.5.3 to v2.9.2 today, so I wonder if that's what fixed it. The header buttons seem to work fine, but I'm using a custom button specified in the ```headerLeft``` of ```navigationOptions``` instead of the default back button. The only thing that is off is that the title font size has changed for my modals. I'll keep playing around with it to see if there are any issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm also still experimenting, but haven't found a better solution than the one in my own SO question.