# React Navigation: Dynamically setting `mode` setting (/ header renders double and back button disappears)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my app I have three screens: `ScreenA`, `ScreenB` and `ScreenC`. They all should have a header and they should all have a back button with the name of the previous screen. I wanted `ScreenA` to be able to open `ScreenB` using the modal animation:

```
const ModalStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ScreenA,
    ScreenB
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "ScreenA",
    mode: "modal"
  }
);
```

And `ScreenA` should also be able to open `ScreenC` using the default sliding animation from right to left. The problem was, that the StackNavigator was already configured with the modal mode. Is there a way to dynamically set the mode? So that from `ScreenA` to `ScreenB` modal is used and from `ScreenA` to `ScreenC` card?

Furthermore how to handle the header in this case? (For the reason why I ask this question, please read further.)

Here is what I tried after reading the documentation. [It describes a similar scenario.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/modal.html)

Here is how this tutorial translated for me:

```
const SlidingStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ScreenA,
    ScreenC
  }
);

const ModalStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    SlidingStack,
    ScreenB
  },
  {
    mode: "modal"
  }
);
```

The problem with this solution is, that the header now renders double when I'm on `ScreenA`. Furthermore when I open the modal `ScreenB` the back button is blank.

### Edit

In my attempt to solve this problem following the documentation, I found a solution for the double header rendering:

```
const SlidingStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ScreenA,
    ScreenC
  }
);

const ModalStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    SlidingStack,
    ScreenB
  },
  {
    mode: "modal",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      const options = {}
      if (navigation.state.routeName === "SlidingStack") options["header"] = null;
      return options;
    }
  }
);
```

The problem with this solution is, that the back buttons still do not have any text.

**Edit:**

Following what I've learned from Pritish, here is the code I ended up with:

```
const IOS_MODAL_ROUTES = ["OptionsScreen"];

let dynamicModalTransition = (
  transitionProps: NavigationTransitionProps,
  prevTransitionProps: NavigationTransitionProps
): TransitionConfig => {
  if (
    IOS_MODAL_ROUTES.some(
      screenName =>
        screenName === transitionProps.scene.route.routeName ||
        (prevTransitionProps && screenName === prevTransitionProps.scene.route.routeName)
    )
  ) {
    return StackViewTransitionConfigs.defaultTransitionConfig(
      transitionProps,
      prevTransitionProps,
      true
    );
  }
  return StackViewTransitionConfigs.defaultTransitionConfig(
    transitionProps,
    prevTransitionProps,
    false
  );
};
```

It uses React Navigation V2's owns transitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going back to the [**docs**](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headerbacktitle)

**`headerBackTitle`:**: Defaults to the previous scene's `headerTitle`

In your implementation, you're trying to move from `ScreenA` to `ScreenB`, where the header of the `ScreenA` is null, *therefore the back button doesn't contain a title.*

There will always be a case (as per your design) that you transition from a *non header screen* to a *header screen*, hence this solution won't work.

A workaround for that would be to create a [Transitioner](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/transitioner.html) with a `default`(a screen transition) and `modal` Transition (a modal transition), and set it in the [`transitionConfig`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig) options of the **StackNavigatorConfig** as

```
let CustomTransitionConfig = () => {
    return {
        screenInterpolator: (sceneProps) => {
            const { position, scene } = sceneProps;
            const { index, route } = scene;
            const params = route.params || {};
            const transition = params.transition || 'default';
            return {
                modal: ModalTransition(index, position),
                default: ScreenTransition(index, position),
            }[transition];
        }
    }
};

createStackNavigator({
...
   {transitionConfig: CustomTransitionConfig}
...
```

and use transition params while navigating if you want to have a modal as

```
this.props.navigation.navigate({routeName: 'ScreenC', params: {transition: 'modal'}}
```

Comment: This is a bit late, but how would I get `ModalTransition()` or `ScreenTransition()`. I can't solve this issue :(

Comment: They have these examples defined [here](https://medium.com/async-la/custom-transitions-in-react-navigation-2f759408a053)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve it using the native transitions from the library.

Comment: @PritishVaidya I couldn't find the ModalTransition in the article or the GitHub project, could you define them in the answer?

Comment: transitonConfig is removed what should i do now?